# Is there a javascript universal chaining method

Tags: javascript

**WARNING: Axios is broken if you use this, but fetch is not.**

For short I'm asking if there is a standard way to chain functions independently of type, with a similar implementation which doesn't polute Native Prototypes:

```js
Object.prototype.pipe = function (func) {
   return func(this)
}
```

<sub>Edit: Use the following if you want to avoid enumerable bugs where the method would appear when enumerating keys of any object, also it's a loose defined method.</sub>

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pipe', {
    value(func) {
        return func(this)
    }
})
```

---

This would permit to do thing like :

```js
const preloadContext = require.context('@/', true, /\.preload\.vue$/)
const preloadComponents = preloadContext
   .keys()
   .map(fileName => {
      const name = fileName
         .split('/')
         .pop()
         .replace(/\.\w+.\w+$/, '')
         .pipe(camelCase)
         .pipe(upperFirst)
      const component = filename
         .pipe(preloadContext)
         .pipe(config => config.default || config)
      Vue.component(name, component)
      return [name, component]
   })
   .pipe(Object.fromEntries)
```

instead of

```js
const preloadContext = require.context('@/', true, /\.preload\.vue$/)
const preloadComponents = Object.fromEntries(preloadContext
   .keys()
   .map(fileName => {
      const name = upperFirst(camelCase(fileName
         .split('/')
         .pop()
         .replace(/\.\w+.\w+$/, '')
      ))
      const config = preloadContext(fileName)
      const component = config.default || config
      Vue.component(name, component)
      return [name, component]
   })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no real standard way. There’s a stage 1 proposal for [an operator that would do it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator), though:

```js
const name = fileName
   .split('/')
   .pop()
   .replace(/\.\w+.\w+$/, '')
   |> camelCase
   |> upperFirst
```

which you can use today with rewriting tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator).

If you don’t want to use a rewriting tool, though, I definitely wouldn’t create `Object.prototype.pipe`. There are still cleaner non-ideal options:

```js
const pipe = (value, fns) =>
    fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), value);
```

```js
const pipe = (value, fns) =>
    fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), value);

const foo = pipe('Mzg0MA==', [
    atob,
    Number,
    x => x.toString(16),
]);

console.log(foo);
```

(Lots of helpful function collections and individual packages implement this.)

Comment: As soon as major browsers and node implement this, this would be accepted answer, but for now it's not native and need the use of babel

Comment: @y.petremann: That there’s no good alternative is why the operator is a proposal at all.